# Remove dependency on inherited abstract class references

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, abstract-class

I am trying to setup a scenario where we can create a common set of models for our workgroup and then implement or extend them if/when needed.

I have the following setup:

```
namespace Workgroup.DomainClasses
{
    public abstract class WorkGroupOrder
    {
       private ICollection<WorkGroupItems> _items;

       protected WorkGroupOrder()
       {
           _items = new List<WorkGroupItems>();
       }
       protected int OrderId { get; set; }
       protected virtual ICollection<WeAccount> Items
       {
           get { return _items; }
           set { _items = value; }
       }
    }
}
```

I would prefer that users not use the base `WorkGroupOrder` so would like to set this up so they are required to implement their own version of the class.  If all is good with the base class it would simply be an empty class calling the base constructor but otherwise properties and functionality could be added.  The idea for this is that the Workgroup domain is much larger than may be necessary for a single project but we'd like to drive all work from this common model.

```
using Workgroup.DomainClasses;
namespace Project.DomainClasses
{
    public class Order : WorkGroupOrder
    {
        public string OrderComment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that I'm required to reference both domain models to implement.  There is an error below in the Testing() method that I must also reference `Workgroup.DomainClasses` in order to instantiate the class.  I'm not that familiar with abstract classes so is this just the nature of the abstract type?  I'd prefer to remove this dependency if possible.

```
using Project.DomainClasses;
namespace Project.DataLayer
{
    public class Testing
    {
        public void Testing()
        {
            Order o1 = new Order();
        }
    }
}
```

A few questions.

1. Does this organization make sense or is there a better way to
       support my desire of providing a common model that could potentially
       be extended?

   How would I access the properties of both the base
       abstract class and the concrete class?  In my Testing() method I am unable
       to access `o1.OrderId` for example.

   I'd like to remove meta-knowledge of the abstract class from the developer.  How would it be best to execute the constructor without explicitly requiring the developer to do so?

Ultimately I'd like to require developers to create their own instance of the class to avoid implementing the base model directly.  I'd also like to build in the proper visibility to prevent them from going directly to the Workgroup objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there are a few different issues in play here.

Firstly, using a namespace to try to segregate out base functionality is not a viable option because all derived classes will need access to the namespace of the base class by default (in order to inherit). Any developers extending your base classes will need access to the namespace containing the base classes.

Controlling access to functionality or data is generally best accomplished using access modifiers (eg, `public`, `protected`, or `private`) or public properties with `public get{ }` and `protected set{ }` or `private set{ }` (ie, getters and setters with different acccess levels). If you wish to hide implementation details from the end users, then an `interface` is the right approach to take (like an API, for example).

Secondly, by marking any class `abstract` you will automatically deny other developers the ability to instantiate that class directly. They will be forced to create a class derived from the `abstract` class (aka, a "concrete" class) in order to use the `abstract` base class's methods and properties.

Third, the reason you couldn't access property `o1.OrderId` in your test code is because that property has an access modifier of `protected`. This means that only the base class and its derived classes can *internally* access this property. To expose it to the end user, it must be marked `public`.

Comment: Regarding your second point, I am attempting to create the concrete class through inheritance.  I also understand the issue of requiring access to the base-level namespace, which is not ideal.  I've seen many use an AutoMapper to sidestep this but I'd prefer to make use of the already existing base-level object.

Comment: What is your primary concern with other developers having access to your base classes? Are you trying to protect proprietary code? Or are you just trying to make life as simple as possible for developers extending your classes?

Comment: The second.  The base classes will be governed by another group and versioned.  The individual projects should only inherit what they need from the base classes and implement their own classes as necessary.

Comment: In this case, I see no reason to not proceed along the path you are taking. Create your abstract base classes and implement all base methods and properties that could / will be of use to the possible derived classes. Then you can compile your project to a "Class Library" (a .DLL file). Other developers then drop this .DLL file into their project, add a reference to it, and they are good to go. If they wish to examine the details of any of your base methods, they can either ask you for the source code or send the DLL through Reflector to see what it's doing.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I do not really understand what you mean with "setup a scenario where we can create a common set of models for our workgroup and then implement or extend them if/when needed". What is a workgroup in your context? And why should (all) other classes derive from it?

Anyway, you cannot use `o1.OrderID` because this property is `protected` which means it is only visible within the scope of `WorkOrderGroup` and subclasses that derive from it. Make this property `public` and you can access it everywhere.

Furthermore, and please take no offence, but it seams that you somewhat struggle with the object-oriented concepts of encapsulation and inheritance. I would advise you to have a look at these concepts (you can e.g. start [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/Poka-yokeDesignFromSmelltoFragrance/)) and get a good understanding what they do and how to use them when implementing functionality. **With the current information, I would not advise you to structure your code like you explained in your question.**

Finally, some general hints on practices in object-oriented languages:

- Favor composition over inheritance: this means that you should extend existing classes by encapsulating them instead of inheriting from them. In most cases this is more flexible.
- Take a look at the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) princples: they provide really good instructions that you should consider on every class you write.
- Take a look at Design Principles and maybe Domain-Driven-Design: there is a lot of guidance on the internet out there with a lot of examples. With every examples you get a better feeling how to approach new problems and how to model them in OOD.

I hope this answer guides you in the correct direction.